# How to match alphanumeric and symbols using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm working with text content in UTF8 encoding stored in variable `$title`.

Using `preg_replace`, how do I append an extra space if the `$title` string is ending with:

- upper/lower case character
- digit
- symbol, eg. `?` or `!`

Comment: Technically you wanna add a space at the end of every string?

Comment: Define *symbol* ... you've got a lot of options to choose from with utf8.

Comment: What you will need is `/u` modifier. The rest is not clear.

Comment: Not everything.  In my situation, `$title` maybe contain other Asian languages, eg. Chinese, Japanese, Korean.  I don't need to appending a space if it's ending with those languages.  Only conditions matching the given cases.

Comment: @CD001 Currently, for symbol, I would only need to match `?` and `!`, rest could be ignored and considered non matching.

Comment: In which case something like `preg_replace('/^(.*)[\w?!]+$/', "$1 ", $string);` should do the job.

Comment: @CD001 Your solution remove the last English character and appending a space, I need to keep everything matched, and add an extra space.

Comment: Heh - sorry, I closed the parenthesis too soon - wasn't really thinking about it too hard I'm afraid, figured someone would offer the correct answer before I'd written it out. `/^(.*[\w?!])$/`

Comment: @CD001 Your solution works perfect for me.  If you can post it as an answer, would be glad to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Oki - put an explanation as to why... I don't like *try this* answers without explanations (which is why I'm generally a bit slow to answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
preg_replace('/^(.*[\w?!])$/', "$1 ", $string);
```

In essence what it does is **if** the string ends in one of your unwanted characters it appends a single space.

If the string doesn't match the pattern, then `preg_replace()` returns the original string - so you're still good.

If you need to expand your list of unwanted endings you can just add them into the character block `[\w?!]`

Answer (score 2):

Using a positive lookbehind before the end of the line.
And replace with a space.

```
$title = preg_replace('/(?<=[A-Za-z0-9?!])$/',' ', $title);
```

Try it [here](https://eval.in/605394)

Comment: It's giving me an warning of: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '$'

Comment: Originally I hadn't enclosed the regex with the forward slashes. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this Pattern Matching below to see if that does it for you.

```
<?php
    // THE REGEX BELOW MATCHES THE ENDING LOWER & UPPER-CASED CHARACTERS, DIGITS
    // AND SYMBOLS LIKE "?" AND "!" AND EVEN A DOT "."
    // HOWEVER YOU CAN IMPROVISE ON YOUR OWN
    $rxPattern  = "#([\!\?a-zA-Z0-9\.])$#"; 
    $title      = "What is your name?";
    var_dump($title);

    // AND HERE, YOU APPEND A SINGLE SPACE AFTER THE MATCHED STRING
    $title      = preg_replace($rxPattern, "$1 ", $title);
    var_dump($title);

   // THE FIRST var_dump($title) PRODUCES:
   // 'What is your name?' (length=18)

   // AND THE SECOND var_dump($title) PRODUCES
   // 'What is your name? ' (length=19) <== NOTICE THE LENGTH FROM ADDED SPACE.
```

You may test it out [HERE](https://eval.in/605368).

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
$title=preg_replace("/.*[\w?!]$/", "\\0 ", $title);
```